# ModuleNotFoundError in Git Bash

Tags: python, tensorflow, git-bash

I am using git bash to run a python file for a Keras-based CNN.

I am facing two issues, both of which give a ModuleNotFoundError:

1) from `main.model.squeezeDet` import  SqueezeDet

It is not recognizing this '`main`' folder, saying no module named '`main`'.

2) import tensorflow as `tf`

I have tensorflow available in an anaconda environment, but I am unable to figure out how to activate that in git bash. So this also says:

```
no module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: 1) We can see neither your code nor libraries. If you don't know what's `main` how do we know?

Comment: 2) In the conda virtualenv directory lookup subdirectory `bin`; find there script called `activate` and source it using bash commnd `source` or just `.` (plain dot). Something like `source path/to/conda/bin/activate`

Comment: I have a folder named squeezedet-keras, which has some folders (images, main, scripts, venv). I created 'venv' using the virtualenv. Now using the git bash, I am trying to run a python file 'train.py' contained in the 'scripts' folder. This file has a code: from main.model.squeezeDet import SqueezeDet, which tries to import 'SqueezeDet' from the 'squeezeDet.py' from the path 'main/model/squeezeDet.py. But when I run this, it gives me the abovementioned error.

Comment: `source venv/bin/activate`